# Combining bash aliases and arguments/parameters

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I have a bash script called `script.sh` and I want to create an alias `runscript`. Now, I know how to create an alias in my bash_profile or bashrc.

However - if I want to run parameters and do the following

```
$ runscript param1 param2
```

Is there something special I need to write in the script or in the alias that allows me to run the alias and the use parameters as well?

Comment: An alias cannot admin multiple parameters. In case of need, you can create a function to handle them, also in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: if your params going to the end of line, simple try `alias bubu=ls` and you can `bubu /etc /bin` for `ls /etc /bin`

Comment: Sorry @jm666 I don't follow - can you elaborate slightly?

Comment: not really, because I said everything. if you do `alias bbb=ls` mean the `bbb` will be alias to `ls`. So when you run `bbb arg1 arg2` it is the same as `ls arg1 arg2`. For more advanced argument handling you should  use shell functions, as told you already @fedorqui. You should always try the example and will see yourself. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [other question - "Accessing Shell parameters inside functions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811815/accessing-shell-parameters-inside-functions) - here is an example:

```
$ ls script
script
$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_aFunction() {
    echo "Parameter 1: ${1}"
    echo "Parameter 2: ${2}"
}

_aFunction
_aFunction "$1" "$2"
_aFunction One Two

$ alias my_alias="./script"
$ my_alias 1 2
Parameter 1:
Parameter 2:
Parameter 1: 1
Parameter 2: 2
Parameter 1: One
Parameter 2: Two
```